how prevent variables being confused with cell references within the NLSolve function
PURPOSE
Solve multiple equations with NLSOLVE in Excel (equations from a circuit analysis)
Content of the cells A1 until A4:
= -X2 + X1 + X3 
= -1 -X3 + X4
= 50 - 10*X3 - 4*X2
=-65*X1 + 10*X3 + 25*X4

With
=NLSOLVE(A1:A4,X1:X4)

I get the correct values for X1, X2, X3, X4
PROBLEM
The original values in the exercise were not X1:X2 but i1, ia, ib, ic.
When I use these variables, it does't work and excel seems to consider these variables as cell range. ok, BUT
QUESTION

Why X1, X2, X3, X4 are not being confused with cells?
how can I use the variables i1, ia, ib, ic?


A solution with the calculator NumWorks:
Define the two variables A and B as matrices.

Press Button var, then press shift and the button just below to enter a matrix as variable.
Store the first  matrix (contains all values of the equations) as A.
Store the second  matrix which contains the results of the previous equations as B
Resolve the equation by the multiplication  (A to the power of -1) * B

